# Mixture Density Networks -- Recovering Conditionals

Tags: neural-networks, deep-learning, mixture-distribution

If we've got a network trained to generate a mixture of Gaussians and we want the conditional distributions based on a set/subset of outputs, can we easily recover these?

Intuitively, yes, we should be able to run the gradients backwards, but it's a bit unclear to me how this would actually work. (It feels like inceptionism)

Take the example of predicting a mixture of just 2 gaussians, so we've got 7 total outputs representing Y (y1,y2):
 - 2 mixing weights 
 - 2 means, 2 variances, 1 correlation

Now I've got some input vector/matrix X, but instead of spitting out this 7 tuple indicating the predicted mixture, I now also know y2 to be, say, 10.

In this case, it's perhaps reasonable to use the properties of gaussians AFTER doing the prediction, but this is quickly intractable as # mixing components increases or we start mixing other families.